# Apple pay PKPaymentauthorizationViewController always returning nil when loaded with Payment request

Tags: ios, objective-c, applepay

I am getting the PK Payment auth view controller instance returned as nil. What is wrong with this code?

```
if([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController canMakePayments])
{
    if ([PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController    canMakePaymentsUsingNetworks:@[PKPaymentNetworkAmex, PKPaymentNetworkMasterCard, PKPaymentNetworkVisa]]) 
    {
        PKPaymentRequest *request = [[PKPaymentRequest alloc] init];
        request.currencyCode = @"USD";
        request.countryCode = @"US";
        request.merchantCapabilities = 0;
        request.requiredBillingAddressFields=PKAddressFieldAll;
        request.merchantIdentifier = @"merchant.com.domain.mine";
        PKPaymentSummaryItem *item = [[PKPaymentSummaryItem alloc] init];
        item.label=@"Merchant";
        item.amount=[NSDecimalNumber decimalNumberWithString:@"10"];
        request.paymentSummaryItems=@[item];
        PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController *viewController =  [[PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController alloc] initWithPaymentRequest:request];
        viewController.delegate = self;
        [self presentViewController:viewController animated:YES   completion:nil];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 10):

Before accessing the `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`, you should configure Apple Pay properly on your iPhone device. If you have not configured Apple Pay on your device you'll get `nil` value for `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController`. You can even find an exception on the console stating "`This device cannot make payment.`"

To configure Apple Pay on your device follow the below steps:

- Go to **Settings**.
- Select **Passbook and Apple Pay** option (if this option is not visible in settings, go to **General -> Language & Region**, change your region to US or UK, after this you'll be able to see the **Passbook & Apple Pay** option in **Settings**)
- Open **Passbook** application from your home screen and configure a valid credit/debit card (US/UK based card only).
- After verifying the added card, run your application you'll get a valid `PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController` instance.

Hope this will help.

Comment: Thanks pradeep. Right now the device configured properly and well we are using it in daily life. canMakePayment returns True.

Comment: Thanks, it's helpful.

Comment: I am Trying with Sanbox tester as detail provided here:https://developer.apple.com/support/apple-pay-sandbox/, but this is not working for my case. It is always giving nil value to me

Comment: @MehulThakkar I am facing the same issue, can't get the sandbox cards to work with UK region, have you managed to solve your issue?

Comment: It's not worked for me.I have done lots of changes but nothing not.

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar issue. It looks like you included it, but for anyone else struggling with this, my problem was not initially supplying merchantCapabilities to the request.

Swift:

```
request.merchantCapabilities = PKMerchantCapability.capability3DS
```

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/passkit/pkmerchantcapability?language=objc

Answer (score 1):

If you are instantiating the supporting networks with raw value, make sure they are done so with the proper capitalization.

```
// Summarized for posting purposes
let networks = ["AmEx", "Visa", "MasterCard", "Discover"].reduce(into: [PKPaymentNetwork]()) { $0.append(PKPaymentNetwork($1)) }

if PKPaymentAuthorizationViewController.canMakePayments(usingNetworks: networks, capabilities: .capability3DS) {
    // Hooray
}
```